# public api for nearby businesses

Tags: api, location-based

I'm looking for an api to give me nearby businesses and venues based on a lat / long + radius.

I was looking at the foursquare api, which serves part of that: it gives venues based on a lat and long but not radius.  Does anyone know of any alternatives?  Does google have something that does this?

Thanks and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo has a [local api](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html) that takes radius as an input